# Switching between launchers of Android Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have two launchers one is default that is provided by Android. Other is user defined.
What i want is for some conditon

```
 If(true)
  {
  // default launcher provided by android starts}

  else
  {
           // User defined launcher starts
  }
```

Also when this activity containing the above code starts, user defined launcher starts.
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: be more precise - when will this code run? what kind of condition do you want?

Comment: I want to start launchers by their names without showing any dialog box to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also create a blank activity, with no UI, and register it as your launcher. Then start other activities as necessary. This might help?

Comment: maybe that might help him - but i don't get it... i absolutely don't know what Rohit wants...